# How can I drop a database from MAMP using the command line

Tags: command-line, mamp

Can someone help me with a command line instruction to drop a single MAMP database?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p`. It'll ask for your password. Then just use the regular MySQL `DROP DATABASE nameofdatabase` command.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I just get the indented -> prompt and the terminal hangs. Is there some extra formatting I need to include? Using MAMP 2.1.4.

Comment: Put a ; in the end of line.

Comment: @jornak What password is this? I've tried the default MAC one it says: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - I then went into PHPMyAdmin and changed the password for the user root to try and still no luck :/